# how to automatically update a .jar, I am finishing up a very small application that I want to be able to have version control on after I deploy it

Tags: java, version-control, osgi, install4j, jgit

I have stumbled across many things, OSGi, Install4j, JWS(Java Web Start deprecated), Jgit, etc. I want to know what the best solution is for a very small java application that will be installed on the companies computers to interface with USB Scales. If our database updates I want to be able to go and update the git repository and have the Jars already on all of the machines update to the new jar when one is available. This small application will be used probably 100 times a day, but is very small. If the jar needs to pause to update that is fine. **I don't want to recreate the wheel**. Is the best option a two part system where one jar is the Updater and one is the application? Please help I am a bit lost on this as most of the information is at least a few years old. I have also found this [Tutorial on OSGi](https://www.baeldung.com/osgi) but not sure it is what I need.

Comment: There are lots of prebuilt wheels, but tool recommendations are explicitly outside our scope, and what's "best" is extremely vague / use-case-centric / opinion-based.

Comment: ok, in your opinion? not looking for anything super complex... don't even care if it has to completely replace the existing jar with the new jar.

Comment: _Shrug_. I've built more than a few update mechanisms, and have my favorite (roughly, [`desync`](https://github.com/folbricht/desync) + [`mkosi`](https://0pointer.net/blog/mkosi-a-tool-for-generating-os-images.html)) but that's for standalone appliances where we had to upgrade the whole OS. There are lots of options when all you care about is a JAR, and exactly which is appropriate for a given use case is fact-intensive; need to dive into the security model, portability needs, available tools, etc etc, and that's outside reasonable SO-question scope.

Comment: ...mind, if you don't care about security this all gets extremely trivial, but not caring about security is how your customers get supply-chain attacks; so responsible folks use asymmetric encryption to sign binaries and ensure that their update mechanism verifies that signature.